# jQuery: function not working when clicking button inside <form runat="server">

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback

With jQuery, in (document).ready I assigned a click function to all buttons of my asp.net (aspx) page.
When I click a button outside , the function works properly.
When clicking a button INSIDE the form, it doesn't work. Why?

Here my default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQuery._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("input").before("ciao");
            });   
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="Button1">Button BEFORE Form</button>
<button id="Button2">Another BEFORE Form</button>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <button id="btStart">Button in Form</button>
    <div>
    <input type="text" value="I like number 1" />
    <input type="text" value="Smile to number 2" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I tried also with jQuery 1.4.2, same problem.

Thanks for letting me know, cheers.

Comment: THANKS A LOT elusive and Kelsey! "return false;" did the job! Normal button or asp.net button... it worked in both cases! Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are clicking a button in a `<form>`, it triggers a submit action. Try adding

```
return false;
```

after

```
$("input").before("ciao");
```

to prevent the default action related to that click event.

Answer (score 1):

It should work but the button is just submitting and refreshing so you are not noticing it.  Since your using asp.net you could do it by just using an `asp:Button` like:

```
<asp:Button ID="yourButton"
    OnClientClick="$('input').before('ciao'); return false;" Text="Test" />
```